# What is the difference in request with LEFT JOIN when it moved under WHERE block?

Tags: mysql

What is the difference in request with LEFT JOIN in mysql 8 :

```
SELECT pboi.id, pboi.status, pboi.expires_at, users.id, users.name, p.id, p.title
    FROM postponed_back_order_items pboi
    LEFT JOIN
        users ON users.id = pboi.creator_id   AND users.status = 'A'
    LEFT JOIN
        products AS p ON p.id = pboi.product_id  AND p.status = 'A'
    WHERE pboi.status = 'P'
```

which returns 3 rows, including 1 rows from products where status != ‘A’

But if to move

```
 AND p.status = 'A'
```

from join block to WHERE BLOCK :

```
SELECT pboi.id, pboi.status, pboi.expires_at, users.id, users.name, p.id, p.title
    FROM postponed_back_order_items pboi
    LEFT JOIN
        users ON users.id = pboi.creator_id   AND users.status = 'A'
    LEFT JOIN
        products AS p ON p.id = pboi.product_id
    WHERE pboi.status = 'P'  AND p.status = 'A'
```

returns only 2 rows excluding 1 rows from products where status != ‘A’

I use 3 joined tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `postponed_back_order_items` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creator_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('I','C','P','O','R') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'I-Invoice, C-Cancelled, P-Processing, O - Completed, R - Refunded',
  `expires_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `qty` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` int unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Cast on client must be used - Money sum = value/100',
  `total_price` decimal(8,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`price` * `qty`)) STORED COMMENT 'Cast on client must be used - Money sum = value/100',
  `manager_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('N','A','I','B') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' COMMENT ' N => New(Waiting activation), A=>Active, I=>Inactive, B=>Banned',
  `membership_mark` enum('N','M','S','G') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' COMMENT ' N => No membership, M - Member, S=>Silver Membership, G=>Gold Membership',
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),



CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creator_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('D','P','A','I') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D' COMMENT ' D => Draft, P=>Pending Review, A=>Active, I=>Inactive',
  `slug` varchar(260) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sale_price` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_stock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_qty` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `discount_price_allowed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `short_description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `published_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins happen before the `WHERE` filter is applied.  So in the following left join:

```sql
products AS p ON p.id = pboi.product_id AND p.status = 'A'
```

Every matching record in the query will be retained, even if there are no matching products with `A` status.  For those records not matching to any product with `A` status, the product columns would select as null values only.

If we move the `p.status = 'A'` condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE p.status = 'A'
```

The left join would happen first, but then any non `A` status products would be entitely filtered off and removed from the result set.